# Does the Cisco 3560-CX support Layer 3 Etherchannel?

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, layer3, etherchannel

Does the Cisco 3560-CX support Layer 3 Etherchannel?  I can see from the specs that this switch supports Layer 2 Etherchannel and that it is a layer 3 compact switch. However, it doesn't have the full feature set of a regular 3560 switch, which makes me hesitate on whether it supports **Layer 3** Etherchannel.  Does anyone that has one of these know? Or can someone point me to some documentation that gives a definitive answer to this?

Note: We don't currently own this switch, I am asking because of an upcoming purchasing decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to find out is to determine the version of IOS that your switch is running. `show version` will get you this information.

Then look up the version of IOS using [Cisco's Feature Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp). You will be able to determine what exactly your version of code supports and what it does not.

Comment: We don't have this switch, I am asking because of an upcoming purchasing decision. I looked up the minimum software version for this switch (15.2(3)E) and tried to find that in the Cisco Feature Navigator. However, I was only able to select 15.2(2)E and after that in the platform dropdown I chose what seemed to be the closest thing to the Cisco 3560CX which was CAT3560C405EX.  However, in the supported features list I wasn't able to see anything relevant to Etherchannel. Although I know it does support Etherchannel from the datasheet. I just don´t know if it supports Layer 3 etherchannel.

Comment: We cannot really assist you with your purchasing decisions as you have to do your own homework by contacting the vendor directly with your questions. Having said that, searching for a Cisco web link at the moment shows no L3 LACP and that is a concern. Don't forget to have all communications with Cisco via email or save the transcript of your chats with their online sales assistant reps.

Comment: @User4565: can you edit in your comment at the bottom of John Jensen's answer?  That way I can mark this answer as "the answer". Thanks...!

Comment: @Anne-of-GG - Methinks John Jensen already gave the best answer :-)   Don't forget to post your findings from Cisco towards the small switch, it may assist many techs in future.

Comment: The numerical version alone usually isn't enough to determine what is and what isn't supported. You're looking for a string like `C3750E-UNIVERSALK9-M` (as an example) as the main identifier, and from there you can choose the numerical version to narrow down what is/isn't supported.

Comment: thanks, according to an online chat with a Cisco Rep, L3 etherchannel isn't supported

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to find out is to use the CLI and look for the relevant commands.  If they are there then it should work.

Even if your box does not support that you can do [load balancing over parallel links](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/modules/ps2033/prod_technical_reference09186a00800afeb7.html).

Comment: what is incorrect about this answer?